# Passsing two VARRAYS to a Procedure to pass them to a Index-By table

Tags: plsql, package, procedure

I try to pass two VARRAYs into a Procedure but when call it to test it I don't get any kind of respond from my database.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PACKAGE PKG_TEST AS
  TYPE PNO IS VARRAY(20) OF VARCHAR(20);
  TYPE QTY IS VARRAY(20) OF INTEGER;
  TYPE indexTest IS TABLE OF NUMBER INDEX BY VARCHAR2(20);
  PROCEDURE blatest(i_PNO IN PNO, i_QTY IN QTY);
END PKG_TEST;
/

CREATE OR REPLACE PACKAGE BODY PKG_TEST AS
  PROCEDURE blatest(i_PNO IN PNO , i_QTY IN QTY)
    IS
      V_COUNT_PNO INTEGER;
      V_COUNT_QTY INTEGER;
      bla_list indexTest;
      name VARCHAR(20);
    BEGIN
      V_COUNT_PNO := i_PNO.COUNT;
      V_COUNT_QTY := i_QTY.COUNT;
    IF V_COUNT_PNO = V_COUNT_QTY THEN
      FOR I IN 1..V_COUNT_PNO LOOP
        bla_list(i_PNO(I)) := i_QTY(I);
      END LOOP;
      name := bla_list.FIRST;
      WHILE name IS NOT null LOOP
        dbms_output.put_line('Name: ' || name || ' is ' || TO_CHAR(bla_list(name)));
        name := bla_list.NEXT(name);
      END LOOP;
    ELSE
      dbms_output.put_line('Amount of Variables is not identical!');
    END IF;
  END blatest;
END PKG_TEST;
/

PKG_TEST.blatest(PKG_TEST.PNO('P123','P124'), PKG_TEST.QTY(2,3));
/
```

And if there is any easier way to fill in a Index-By table I dynamicly I am more than happy to read this ^^. Thanks in advance!

Comment: PKG_TEST.PNO('P123','P124') --> This collection declaration you need to have it dynamically?

Answer (score 0):

Call it as below, then you will get response:

```
set serveroutput on;

BEGIN
   pkg_test.blatest (pkg_test.pno ('P123', 'P124'), pkg_test.qty (2, 3));
END;
```

Comment: Ah I did it without the begin and end statements ... sorry for that... Thank you so much!